# Radio button to change JCombo Data

Tags: java, swing, radio-button, jcombobox, buttongroup

Looking for a way to change the data outputted to the combo box by selecting the radio buttons, but the data is being pulled in off a text file and saved into an array and then passed back into JCOMBO array list. sorry if question is a big vague i was not to sure how to word it. but the files are separated by two different TXT files which i can easily return data from.

```
ArrayList<String> stations = Reader("Default.txt");

    JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<>(stations.toArray(new String[stations.size()]));
    JRadioButton belgrave = new JRadioButton("Belgrave Line");
    belgrave.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            cb.removeAllItems();
            stations.clear();
            ArrayList<String> stations = Reader("Belgrave.txt");
            JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<>(stations.toArray(new String[stations.size()]));
        }
    });
    JRadioButton glenwaverly = new JRadioButton("Glen Waverly Line");
    glenwaverly.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            cb.removeAllItems();
            stations.clear();
            ArrayList<String> stations = Reader("Glenwaverly.txt");
            JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<>(stations.toArray(new String[stations.size()]));
        }
    });
    ButtonGroup bG = new ButtonGroup();
    JButton apply = new JButton("Touch on ?");
    JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
```

Comment: The attached example does not contain any effort to handle the logic of radio buttons changing content of the combbobox.

Comment: yea because i have no idea of anyway to know how to change via a radio button

Comment: *"sorry if question is a big vague"*  ..What 'question'?  So far as I can see, you have not asked any question, just given a requirement and a (uncompilable) template of your work for others to complete.

Comment: Radio button to change JCombo Data

i have radio buttons i want to know how selecting them can change data. of the JCOMBO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much like the action listener that you added into the `apply` and `cancel` button you will need to apply an action listener to the radio button as well.

And then do something like the following.

```
private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    //suppose this is your file input, that you will have to read
    String[] test = { "Bird", "Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Pig" };
    //your combobox name supposed it is combo
    //remove all the previous items
    combo.removeAllItems();
    //add all the items of the array(there is no addAll method)
    for(int i=0; i<test.length; i++)
        combo.addItem(test[i]);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Note that reading from a TXT file and parsing the data as an Array is related with the structure of your txt. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961522/how-to-read-a-specified-string-from-an-input-file-then-read-the-next-word-after/20961660#20961660) for how to read a txt line by line.

---

## EDIT

In your listeners you are creating a new local combobox . However `cb` inside the listeners is not the same as `cb` outside of the listeners, it is simply a variable that is created & known only inside the method. You need to directly call cb without creating a new object.

Replace this `JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<>(stations.toArray(new String[stations.size()]))`

with that

```
String[] items = stations.toArray(new String[stations.size()];
for(int i=0; i<items.length; i++) 
      cb.addItem(items[i]);
```

Comment: hey, thanks i tried doing it with a normal action listener. BUT it seems to just clear the JCOMBO box without inserting any of the data. i will update the code to show you what is there